# UIL and android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in Android – Marshmallow

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, android-6.0-marshmallow

After adding UIL to my project, I also add permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But for android project with targetSdkVersion="23" (marshmallow) I need to 
check some "dangerous" permission ( such as WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ) before use.

For example:

```
if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
}
```

But how can I check it? I dont know where UIL use it.

Maybe I misunderstanding or miss something from documentation.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: one thing you can do is configure UIL to use the `context.getCacheDir` as cache, which does not require permissions, as it is a private folder

Comment: Also note that `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` implies `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Therefore, the latter is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But how can I check it?

Use that code, in your own activity or fragment, to check for the permission, before you try using anything from UIL.

Unless the library that you use happens to have activities or fragments, and therefore might be able to `requestPermissions()` itself, you have to `requestPermissions()` before using the library, for any `dangerous` permissions required by that library.

As you note, you have no idea where UIL uses those permissions, and even if you knew for today's UIL, you might not know where UIL uses it tomorrow. Hence, you have to check for, and request if needed, the permissions before doing *anything* with UIL.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought about it and now sure. UIL init in "public class MyAppApplication extends Application" class. Is that a good idea to check permission there ?

Comment: @Sever: You are welcome to check for the permission there, but you can only *request* the permission from an activity or fragment.